# High volume Web API throughput

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, azure, asp.net-web-api

In the following example, imagine that the 'Composition API' is being called at rate of between 100 and 500 requests per second. For each incoming requests, it then has to make requests to 3 services to compose a response for the client.

- The 'Composition API' component is an Azure Cloud Service
- All API methods are async all the way down the stack
- There can be sudden bursts of requests, the incoming rate can change from 100 rps to 500 rps within 60 seconds.
- The services it depends on are all REST APIs over HTTPS
- All the services it depends on have an SLA to respond within 1 second.

[image: Simple API Architecture]

Please ignore Azure scaling and caching from this question, it is purely a best practice for network throughput exercise.

The composition API component is going to be making lots of outbound HTTP requests, and needs to respond quickly to changes in request volume.

This [command script](https://github.com/Aaronontheweb/azure-webroleperformance-scripts/blob/master/upgradeIISthreadcount.cmd), which is based on the [Microsoft recommendations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998549.aspx#scalenetchapt06_topic8) (I know it's a 2004 article!) allows you tweak connection and threading setting when the role starts up

- ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit
- ThreadPool - WorkerThreads \ IOThreads

**Q:** ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit has been Int32.MaxValue since .Net 4.5 - should it still follow the  (12 * # of CPUs) formula?

**Q:** What other settings would you set in order to achieve maximum concurrency, with no timeouts due to request queuing? e.g.

ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

I've seen a few different approaches to this - interested to know if anyone else has high traffic experience and that settings you've utilised in order to solve the above problems.